# Search Engine Optimization forums mybb vs. vbulletin

Tags: seo, vbulletin, mybb

What forum software tends to have a better ranking on google? For instance if I had 2 of the same forums with same titles and names, which would be ranked higher in google? This is not an opinion question this is a real fact question.

So vBulletin or MyBB?

Comment: Saying it is a factual question doesn't make it a factual question.

Comment: In this case it does, as this is not an opinion, I'm looking for a straight clear difference between forum software x and forum software y and how they work accordingly with google. In no way is this an opinion, it is a comparison I suppose but a factual one not opinionated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here relate to a specific programming problem. For example, you could ask (hypothetically) about specific HTML or CSS syntax you are attempting to use in your forum's backend for improving SEO. This question seems like a better fit for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

vbulletin has vbseo plugin which is developed and manteined by professionists...

mybb does not have any working seo plugin at the moment (afaik)

Answer (score 0):

No amount of SEO built-in in a forum package is going to give you better results unless you have good content. Even a site using a non-SEO tuned forum package will rank well in engines if there is lots of content for the search engines to index.

Answer (score -3):

Let's compare the SEO capabilities of the popular forum software options, MyBB and vBulletin:

**MyBB:**

MyBB is an open-source forum software with a strong user community.
It offers customizable URLs, allowing you to optimize the URL structure of your forum for better search engine visibility.
MyBB supports meta tags, including meta descriptions and keywords, which are important for on-page SEO optimization.
It includes features like XML sitemaps, aiding search engine crawlers in efficiently indexing your forum content.
MyBB provides a range of plugins and extensions that can enhance SEO, such as SEO-friendly pagination and canonical URLs.

vBulletin:

vBulletin is a commercial forum software with a long history and a large user base.
Similar to MyBB, vBulletin allows customization of URLs to create SEO-friendly addresses for forum pages.
It has built-in support for meta tags and integrates with popular SEO plugins.
vBulletin offers features for generating XML sitemaps, facilitating search engine discovery and indexing of your forum content.
It provides tools for managing redirects, useful when making changes to forum structure or URLs.

Both MyBB and vBulletin can be optimized for SEO, but the level of optimization achievable depends on your technical expertise, customization options, and the availability of plugins or extensions. Remember that SEO success is influenced not only by the forum software but also by content quality, user engagement, and other off-page SEO factors.

When selecting between MyBB and vBulletin, consider evaluating their SEO features along with other aspects such as user community, customization capabilities, support, and overall suitability for your forum needs.